# Not sure how to display my api data onto my react component in my react app

Tags: reactjs, api

I was wondering if someone could help me out with my problem.

First let me display my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Form, Card, Button, Jumbotron, Container, Col, Row, CardDeck } from "react-bootstrap"
import Navibar from "../components/navbar"
import axios from "axios"


function Home(){
    const [type, setType] = useState()
    const [genrelist, setGenrelist] = useState()
    const [start_year, setStart_year] = useState()
    const [start_rating, setStart_rating] = useState()

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://unogsng.p.rapidapi.com/search',
            params: {
                type: type,
                genrelist: genrelist,
                start_year: start_year, 
                start_rating: start_rating, 
                end_rating: "10",
                orderby: 'rating',
                limit: '100',
                countrylist: '78',
                audio: 'english',
                end_year: '2020'
            },
            headers: {
                'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'unogsng.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        };
        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

   
   
        return (
            <>
                <Navibar />
                <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mt-5"
                    style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
                    <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "800px" }}>
                        <Jumbotron>
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={6}>
                                    <Form style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                                        <Form.Group>
                                            <Form.Row>
                                                <Form.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                                                    Genre
                                                </Form.Label>
                                                <Col xs={7}>
                                                    <Form.Control size="lg" as="select" placeholder="Large text" name="genrelist" onChange={e => setGenrelist(e.target.value)} >
                                                        <option value="899">Action and Adventure</option>
                                                        <option value="4698">Animation</option>
                                                        <option value="1492">Sci-Fi and Fantasy</option>
                                                        <option value="9744">Fantasy</option>
                                                        <option value="7424">Anime</option>
                                                        <option value="783">Children and Family</option>
                                                        <option value="9736">Comedies</option>
                                                        <option value="8673">Documentaries</option>
                                                        <option value="5763">Dramas</option>
                                                        <option value="9327">Sports</option>
                                                        <option value="8711">Horror Films</option>
                                                        <option value="26126">Crime Docuseries</option>
                                                        <option value="7992">TV Animated Comedies</option>
                                                    </Form.Control>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Form.Row>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                        <br />
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <Form.Group as={Row}>
                                                <Form.Label as="legend" column="lg" lg={2}>
                                                    Type
                                                </Form.Label>
                                                <Col sm={10}>
                                                    <Form.Check
                                                        id="movie"
                                                        name="type"
                                                        value="movie"
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        label="Movies"
                                                        onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <Form.Check
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        label="Tv Shows"
                                                        name="type"
                                                        id="series"
                                                        value="series"
                                                        onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <br />
                                        <Form.Group>
                                            <Form.Row>
                                                <Form.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                                                    IMDB Rating
                                                </Form.Label>
                                                <Col xs={7}>
                                                    <Form.Control size="lg" as="select" name="start_rating"  onChange={e => setStart_rating(e.target.value)}  >
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    </Form.Control>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Form.Row>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                        <br />
                                        <Form.Group>
                                            <Form.Row>
                                                <Form.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                                                    Start Year
                                                </Form.Label>
                                                <Col xs={7}>
                                                    <Form.Control size="lg" as="input" name="start_year" onChange={e => setStart_year(e.target.value)}/>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Form.Row>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                        <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="w-100">Generate!</Button>
                                    </Form>
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={6}>
                                    <CardDeck >
                                        <Card>
                                            <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
                                            <Card.Body>
                                                <Card.Title>Card title</Card.Title>
                                                <Card.Text>
                                                  
                                            </Card.Text>
                                            </Card.Body>
                                        </Card>
                                    </CardDeck>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Jumbotron>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </>
        )
    
}

export default Home
```

So basically this page manipulates the API call with whatever data the user inputs into the form. When the user hits the generate button, it console.logs the api data with the relevant information the user selected with the form. Now I want to display one item in the array that the api calls randomly to the card at the bottom of the code. But I'm not sure how to take the information from the handlesumbit function and place it onto the card. If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a card information variable as a state :

```
const [cardDetails, setCardDetails] = React.useState("")
```

In your displayed card :

```
<Card.Text> {cardDetails} </Card.Text>
```

Then, when your function returns a value, set the value in the state :

```
axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            setCardDetails(response.data) // The card details coming from your API ! 
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: and then I can set the data on the card using cardDetails?

Comment: So i tried doing {cardDetails} in my card.text but it gave me an error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {elapse, total, results}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. So I tried mapping the cardDetails like cardDetails.map(details =>()) around the card but it gave me another error saying cannot read property map of undefined

Comment: Hey Matt - so that actually kind of worked - indeed you ll need to map that object, if you want to prove that this worked, try with response.data.total first 
=> setCardDetails(response.data.total) 
Then it's up to you how you display that object

Comment: Yup you're correct! It works! My problem was that I didnt set the initial cardDetail state to an empty array

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the feedback ! Happy coding !